# Vb.net Zoom/Selection Box for Chart slow

Tags: vb.net, charts, line, paint

I have a chart which displays various data. The user is able to click on the chart (1st click), and a box will draw to wherever their mouse moves. On the second click, the selected area will become the new bounds of the chart (zooms in).

I do this by drawing 4 lines in the paint event for the chart, and by calling chart.invalidate each time the mouse moves to force the paint event.

It works really well for fewer than 1000 data-points, but passed that it becomes quite laggy. I'm wondering if there is a way that I can do this without repainting the chart each time the mouse is moved (as I think that this is the issue)

I have also tried this using a custom "floating line" which drew over all controls on the form (incl. the chart) but I experienced ghost-lines (think: moving a windows XP window quickly). I think this was an unavoidable error from constantly moving the lines' locations.

Any ideas/thoughts are appreciated.

Repaint Code:

```
Private Sub Chart1_Paint(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.PaintEventArgs) Handles      Chart1.Paint
    Dim arbitraryPen As New Pen(Brushes.Black, 1)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(arbitraryPen, point1.x, point1.y, point2.x, point1.y)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(arbitraryPen, point1.x, point1.y, point1.x, point2.y)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(arbitraryPen, point1.x, point2.y, point2.x, point2.y)
    e.Graphics.DrawLine(arbitraryPen, point2.x, point1.y, point2.x, point2.y)
    arbitraryPen.Dispose()
End Sub
```

Comment: Unsure why this is tagged `C#`. Removed tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run into this before. My solution was to create an image of the chart in the `MouseDown` event (of the container holding the chart), and add that to the window on top of the chart. On the `MouseMove` event, I drew the lines as you do - but didn't call `chart.Invalidate()`. On the `MouseUp` event, I removed the image of the chart, and performed the zoom. It's kind of hack-ish, but I've discovered that's the case with a lot of things when dealing with a lot of data points in these charts.

ETA code to create the image and display it

```
    private void CreateImagePanel()
    {
        Bitmap image = new Bitmap(Chart.Width, Chart.Height);
        Chart.DrawToBitmap(image, Chart.ClientRectangle);

        Panel panel = new Panel();
        SetDoubleBuffered(panel);
        panel.BackgroundImage = image;
        panel.Width = Chart.Width;
        panel.Height = Chart.Height;
        panel.Location = Chart.Location;
        panel.Paint += PaintRectangle;
        panel.Name = "imagePanel";
        _imagePanel = panel;

        Chart.Parent.Controls.Add(panel);
        panel.BringToFront();
    }
```

`_imagePanel` is a private member of the class, so the panel can be easily removed. `SetDoubleBuffered` is another private method, which could be easily modified into an extension method:

```
    private void SetDoubleBuffered(Control c)
    {
        if (SystemInformation.TerminalServerSession) return;
        PropertyInfo property = typeof(Control).
            GetProperty("DoubleBuffered", BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance);
        property.SetValue(c, true, null);
    }
```

The `PaintRectangle` event of the image panel is handled to just draw the selection rectangle. In the `MouseMove` event, the image panel is `Invalidated`, forcing a redraw of the panel and thus the rectangle. Private properties are used to store the bounds of the rectangle.

Comment: I really like this solution... Are you able to give some more specifics? How did you create the image and how did you display it?

Comment: Perfect explanation. Works brilliantly. I appreciate the help, and I will up-vote the answer as soon as I get the reputation (I'm new here). Thanks!